# Build array of arrays for 3 in a row matching in a 3x3 grid

Tags: javascript

I am building a simple 3 in a row game using a 3x3 grid. I need to build an array of the possible outcomes with using square IDs.

This array would look like:

```
possibilities: [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8]
]
```

I was able to accomplish this task with the following code:

```
const row1 = []
const row2 = []
const row3 = []
const row4 = []
const row5 = []
const row6 = []
const row7 = []
const possibilities= []

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) row1.push(i)
for (let i = 0; i <= 6; i += 3) row2.push(i)
for (let i = 0; i <= 8; i += 4) row3.push(i)
for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i += 3) row4.push(i)
for (let i = 2; i <= 8; i += 3) row5.push(i)
for (let i = 3; i <= 5; i++) row6.push(i)
for (let i = 6; i <= 8; i++) row7.push(i)

possibilities.push(row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7)
```

I'm going to have to do the same with a 4x4 and a 5x5 grid. I am wondering is there a better way/more efficient method to do this? This works but it seems messy and tiresome.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What patterns can you see in the code you've written? Perhaps you can combine them? Is there a way to make it more generic to allow for any size grid?

Comment: When you say, 4x4 or 5x5 grid, are you still looking for 3 in a row, or would it become 4 or 5 in a row?

Comment: I am looking for just 3x3 for now. If there was an efficient solution I would just adapt it later on for different size grids.

Comment: There is nothing more efficient than the array literal you defined in the first code block for 3x3. Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry for the mixup the literal at the top is the output I am expecting. I should have defined it. I have edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just looking for the most efficient way to define the `possibilities` array for 3x3, then just use an array literal, like you have at the top of your question.

If however, you want something generic, which can take any grid size not less than 3, and produce all possibilities for 3-in-a-row, then you could use this function. But obviously there is nothing more efficient than an array literal.

```js
function getPossibilities(length) {
    function triplets(height, width, step, offset=0) {
        return Array.from({length: height * width}, (_, i) => {
            let start = offset + Math.floor(i / width) * length + i % width;
            return [start, start+step, start+step*2];
        });
    }

    return [
        ...triplets(length, length - 2, 1), // horizontal
        ...triplets(length - 2, length, length), // vertical
        ...triplets(length - 2, length - 2, length + 1), // backslash diagonal
        ...triplets(length - 2, length - 2, length - 1, 2) // slash diagonal
    ];
}

console.log(getPossibilities(4));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need three loops. One for horizontal, one for vertical and one for diagonal solutions.

You can also factor-in the winning streak size and use it for controlling the loops.

So an all encompassing solution would be

```js
function uniqueArrays(array) {
  const set = new Set(array.map(JSON.stringify));
  return Array.from(set).map(JSON.parse);
}

function getPossibilities(sizeX, sizeY, sizeWin) {
  const possibilities = [];
  // horizontal
  for (let y = 0; y < sizeY; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x <= sizeX - sizeWin; x++) {
      const possibility = [];
      for (let pos = 0; pos < sizeWin; pos++) {
        possibility.push(y * sizeX + x + pos);
      }
      possibilities.push(possibility);
    }
  }
  // vertical
  for (let x = 0; x < sizeX; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y <= sizeY - sizeWin; y++) {
      const possibility = [];
      for (let pos = 0; pos < sizeWin; pos++) {
        possibility.push(y * sizeX + x + pos * sizeX);
      }
      possibilities.push(possibility);
    }
  }
  // diagonal
  for (let x = 0; x <= sizeX - sizeWin; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y <= sizeY - sizeWin; y++) {
      const possibility = [];
      for (let pos = 0; pos < sizeWin; pos++) {
        possibility.push((y + pos) * sizeX + x + pos);
      }
      possibilities.push(possibility);
    }
  }
  return uniqueArrays(possibilities);
}

console.log('3x3, 3 in a row :', JSON.stringify(getPossibilities(3, 3, 3)));
console.log('4x4, 3 in a row :', JSON.stringify(getPossibilities(4, 4, 3)));
console.log('4x4, 4 in a row :', JSON.stringify(getPossibilities(4, 4, 4)));
```